# Read typescript file using nodejs application

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have an application which is built using **node.js**, **commander.js** and **inquirer.js**.
I have to read the typescript file whose absolute path is known. 
I am using the `ts-simple-ast` npm module to read the source file.
Below is the code for reading the file using the `ts-simple-ast`.

```
import { Project } from "ts-simple-ast";
const path = process.cwd() + "/src/something/foo.ts";
const file = project.addExistingSourceFile(path);
```

This `ts-simple-ast` helps to get the compiler version of typescript file.
But then I have to find object in the typescript file and then create the json object from ts file.
Below is the example of `.ts` file that I have to read.

```
import { a } from '../app/fac/a';
export function abc() {
    return new a();
  }

 export const conf: conf= {
 ddh: 'http://foo/something/foo',
 h: {
      dH: {
            'c': 'j',
            user: 'abc'
          },
      mH: []
   },
 b: false,
 d: true
 }
```

But I end up getting all the values in the form of string even the spaces have some string value.

**Expected Output**

```
{
 "ddh":"http://foo/something/foo",
 "h": {
       "dH":{
              "c": "j",
              "user": "abc"
            },
       "mH": []
      },
  "b": false,
  "d": true
}
```

I have tried to search everywhere but I didn't find any proper solution to read the typescript file from node application and then manipulating accordingly.